# C# execute a .sh file, then the program is freezing

Tags: c#, shell, cmake

I am having issues with running this .sh file through C# on MacOS. I have tried using the following code, but it doesn't seem to work. The .sh file does not execute and I don't get any errors. Can anyone help me figure out what's going wrong?

```bash
cmake -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR=arm64 -DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES=arm64 ..
make -j24
```

```cs
public static ProcessStartInfo GetMacOSStartInfo(string path)
{
    string fileName = "/bin/bash";
    string argument = path;
    return new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = fileName,
        Arguments = argument,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
    };
}
```

Comment: Try `UseShellExecute = true`.  The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66787416/10024425

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working. I don't get any points for an upvote on a comment, but I do if the post referenced in the URL receives an upvote.