How to double quote commands inside a quote on bash using C#?
Problem
Bash
Using bash directly on a ssh terminal, the following command works:
/bin/bash -c 'var="Hello World!"; echo "$var"'

It outputs:

Hello World!

C#
Using the following example code, it raises an error:
using System.Diagnostics;

string command = "-c 'var=\"Hello World!\"; echo \"$var\"'";
Console.WriteLine("Command is: " + command);
string response = SendCommand(command);
Console.WriteLine("Response: " + response);

string SendCommand(string command)
{
    string processResponse = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "/bin/bash",
            Arguments = command,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
        };

        Process shellProcess = new Process()
        {
            StartInfo = startInfo,
        };

        shellProcess.Start();
        StreamReader outputStreamReader = shellProcess.StandardOutput;
        StreamReader errorStreamReader = shellProcess.StandardError;

        string output = outputStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
        string error = errorStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
        if (output != string.Empty)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Process Output Message: {0} ", output);
            processResponse = output;
        }

        shellProcess.WaitForExit(100);
        if (shellProcess.ExitCode != 0)
        {
            if (error != string.Empty)
            {
                processResponse = error;
                Console.WriteLine("Process Error Message: {0} for command {1}.", error, command);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error to Send Process Command: " + ex.Message);
    }

    return processResponse;
}

Error:
Command is: -c 'var="Hello World!"; echo "$var"'

Error to Send Process Command: Input string was not in a correct format.

Response: echo: -c: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''

echo: -c: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Double quotes inside double quotes
On bash the following command:
/bin/bash -c "var=\"Hello World! \"; echo \"\$var\""

Outputs:

Hello World!

When changing the string on C#:
string command = "-c \"var=\\\"Hello World\\!\\\"; echo \\\"$var\\\"\"";

It worked! However, it is strange the error raised using single quote. This behavior is unexpected and don't work when using C#.

p.s.: The difference between the bash and C# syntax for this command was that $ had to contain a backlash on a ssh terminal and on C# the backlack \\ did not have to be sent. It is strange, since $ inside double quotes means a special character and not a string.

Question
The output command seems to be the same as the used directly on the ssh terminal.
How to send a command using C# as the ssh terminal?

What are you actually trying to do that needs bash to be called from C#? In most cases you can just call whichever command directly rather than via bash.

It is a long command, with loops and ifs, it uses bash, because the default library don't support Linux correctly...

{output} is a wrong format string, it should be {0}

@shingo Oh sorry, I use a logger function with Serilog and forgot to change for Console.WriteLine. Going to update the question

Wouldn't it be easier to write to a script file and execute that? Ignoring the obvious attack vectors of that, it should still be more reliable than what is shown above.

Yeah, but the app has the correct rights to run those commands... So I wanted to avoid using the scripts. But I think it will be easier to change the OS build (that can take hours to compile), than using C#.

ProcessStartInfo parses its Arguments using weird quoting rules that're different from anything else I've seen -- see MS's documentation. I'd recommend making ArgsEcho like in their docs, seeing what it prints when you use that instead of bash directly on the shell command line (i.e. see what it looks like when the command is passed properly), then try again from C# and try to get the output to match.

Did you try UseShellExecute = true;? Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66787416/10024425,  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/raw-string, and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim

Yes, still get the error echo: -c: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `'' echo: -c: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file. The official documentation states that the default usage is UseShellExecute=true for Net Framework and UseShellExecute=false for Net Core

To simply things a bit can you use the @  you won't need so many escape chars e.g   string command = @"-c ""var=""Hello World!""; echo ""$var""""";
